# Axios response.data returning different data vs network raw response

Tags: javascript, axios

Im using Axios and Javascript to perform simple HTTP requests. Running a simple GET request I get this raw response from the network tab of inspect.

```
 "options": {
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "VA",
        "value": "12345"
      },
      {
        "key": "TX",
        "value": "54321"
      },
      {
        "key": null,
        "value": "11111"
      }
    ]
  }
```

However Axios `request.data` is giving me

```
 "options": {
    "values": [
      {
        "key": null,
        "value": "12345"
      },
      {
        "key": null,
        "value": "54321"
      },
      {
        "key": null,
        "value": "11111"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Any reason why Axios is parsing this incorrectly?
Thanks!

Comment: Is the request you are making to your own server or some other page?

Comment: To my own server, it sends back the correct data shown first in the raw response

Comment: Can you add the code of how you are running the axios request and requesting data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issue. I'm using Vue and the data was being manipulated incorrectly by a component before the console.log was taking place.